# Scrolling Content while Header/Footer Remains Stationary

Tags: html, css

I have a website where the header/footer is to remain stationary at the top/bottom of the screen while the content scrolls. I have been following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399875/scroll-page-content-within-specific-area) that explains how to achieve this effect which sort of works for me. As you scroll down the content, you will notice that the background-image for the content becomes chopped off. I am confused to why this is happening as I have set the background image to `repeat-y`. I also noticed that the footer appears to be hiding some of the content as well.

To achieve this content-only scrolling effect, I added `position: fixed;` to the header/footer. I left the content with `position: absolute;` to keep the footer fixed to the bottom of the screen.

-> [**Link to website**](http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/la4/template.html)

Comment: Unless the content background is supposed to move, you might also try pinning it in place: `background: url(../img/body.png) 160px 0 fixed;`

Comment: Just fyi, on my screen the footer is about 30px away from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I wanted the content background to move :)

Comment: @JakeParis Which browser are you using?

Comment: FFx... whoops it's time to update versions again! There. Firefox 12.0

Comment: fixed position is all you need here, you do not need to set absolute positioning on the content.  Also, I looked at your site and now I'm hungry.

Comment: @Madbreaks Thank you. Those are just place holder images. The real photos will be even better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First off, add `bottom: 0` to your footer. That will bring it down to touch the bottom.
2. Now, take `position: absolute` off `#content`.
3. Lastly, add extra padding at the top and bottom of `#content` so that your text won't get hidden behind the header/footer.

Firebug tells me that will solve the problem on your site. [Ask him yourself](http://getfirebug.com).

Comment: Do you mean like `height: 250px`? The problem is that I will not know the height of the content for every page.

Comment: That sort of worked. If I were to shorten the content of the page to just a few lines, the background-image does not tile all the way down to the footer.

Comment: Cool. Never knew that tag existed. As I won't know the `min-height` of each user's screen, I'll look into adding `min-height` with JavaScript. Or is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: Just add a min-height that's at least large enough for most people. I have a `1680 x 1050` screen and `450px` was big enough for me.

Comment: I tried that, but that meant that the scroll bar was larger then it needed to be if the window height is less then 1050.